# Papyrus vs UML2 plugin

Tags: papyrus, uml-eclipse-plugin

I am looking at UML tools and see that there are at least two that integrate into Eclipse: Papyrus and Eclipse UML2.  How do they compare?  The UML2 plugin does not seem to have been updated for several years and there are nearly no followers or questions in the uml-eclipse-plugin tag in stackoverflow for it.  Is it superseded by Papyrus? Or at least have most users moved on to Papyrus?